# color does not change based on the value of current/max

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive and it seems to work fine on first load:

```
app.directive('myBar',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div class="container" style="border-right:2px #9E9E9E dotted;width:102px;height:17px;"><div class="box max" style="width: {{max}}px;z-index:-1;"></div><div class="box" style="width: {{current}}px; margin-top:-20px;z-index:99999999;" ng-class="{\'greater\': current >= max, \'less\': current < max}"">{{current}}</div></div>',
            scope : {
                current: '@',
                max: '@'
            }
        };
    });
```

but when I am trying to change the values of current/max, the color is not changing:

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp', []);
    app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.chargeability = [{ date: '15-Sep-13', max: 100, current: 50 },
        { date: '30-Sep-13', max: 100, current: 100 },
        { date: '15-Oct-13', max: 80, current: 50}];
        $scope.ytd = 122;
    });
```

on first load...this seems to be working fine but the problem exists when I try to change the values of max and/or current...it no longer follows the ng-class inside the template...

```
ng-class="{\'greater\': current >= max, \'less\': current < max}
```

am I lacking something? Thanks for throwing an idea to solve the issue

Comment: Show html code where you declare the directive, and how do you update the values of current and max.

Comment: Hi Chandermani...<div ng-repeat="charge in chargeability">
        <my-bar current="{{charge.current}}" max="{{charge.max}}"></my-bar>current:{{charge.current}} max:{{charge.max}}
        <div style="clear:both;height:6px;"></div>
    </div>

Comment: I am just updating the values of current and max manually...

Comment: Changing value inside directive or `controller`.

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rmcdjs/ukhju/

Comment: I am manually changing the value in the controller

Comment: Well i don't see your change, but i updated the fiddle with what the basic idea is http://jsfiddle.net/Zghuu/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call $apply() to force angular to do a digest cycle when you update the values of current and max

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
 // update values here, for example..
 $scope.current = newCurrentVal;
 $scope.max = newMaxVal;
});
```

Comment: where should I place this?

Comment: "but when I am trying to change the values of current/max". You put it where you are changing the values. $scope.$apply tells angular to apply the changes you just made to the scope values (current/max) to the page. So you need to call $scope.$apply() directly after you update current or max

Comment: can you show me a fiddle to serve as an example? Im new to angular that's why..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. To test it use `$timeout`. This is actually what I did:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.chargeability = [{
        date: '15-Sep-13',
        max: 100,
        current: 10
    }, {
        date: '30-Sep-13',
        max: 60,
        current: 0
    }, {
        date: '15-Oct-13',
        max: 80,
        current: 10
    }];

    $scope.ytd = 122;

 var stop;
  $scope.increase = function() {
    stop = $timeout(function() {
    // console.log($scope.chargeability[0].current);
             if ($scope.chargeability[0].current < $scope.chargeability[0].max) {
                 $scope.chargeability[0].current = $scope.chargeability[0].current + 1;
              $scope.increase();
           } else {
               $timeout.cancel(stop);
             }
    }, 100);
  };
}]);



app.directive('myBar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            current: '@',
            max: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="container" style="width:102px;height:17px;"><div class="box max" style="width: {{max}}px;z-index:-1;"></div><div class="box" style="width: {{current}}px; margin-top:-20px;z-index:99999999;" ng-class="{\'greater\': current >= max, \'less\': current < max}""></div></div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ffT9QRyXO4leFpTIA3cH?p=info)</kbd>

Comment: Yes it works on initial load...but when you try to manually update the chargeability scope, and try to run it again..the color remains the same..it's not being updated. It seems the color is being cached or something